# Usage of comma after `thank`

Tags: commas

In the acknowledgment of a manuscript I have the following structure
(the reason for thanking A, B, C, D, E, F are different):

`I wish to thank A and B for ..., C and D for ..., and E and F for ....`

Isn't it better to put a comma after thank? I mean to write

`I wish to thank, A and B for ..., C and D for ..., and E and F for ....`

Comment: Khan is quite correct in his answer.  Think of it this way: You write "I like apples, oranges, and pears" not "I like **,** apples, oranges, and pears."  The same principle applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use the comma after the verb thank.

When there is a list of items after a verb, you don't use a comma before the first item.